# Show content in title when text-overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

CSS3 introduces [`text-overflow`](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/) so you can hide overflowing text and even add ellipses.

If the text is overflowing and hidden, I would like to show it as a tooltip when hovered.

The easiest way to do this is to add the text to the `title` attribute of the element. However that will make the text show whether it is overflowing or not.

I only want to show the tooltip when overflowed.

so if I had this:

```
<span>some text here</span>
<span>some more text here</span>
```

and it rendered like this:

> some text here
>
> some more...

The first one would have no tooltip since there is no need and the second would have a tooltip that showed:

> some more text here

Is there any way to set this up?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with pure CSS. Can you use Javascript?

Comment: @KennyTM sure.. jquery is the framework I prefer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS alone, and I think any Javascript solution will depend on how your HTML is structured. However, if you have HTML structured like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <span class="bar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</span>
  <span class="bar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
</div>
```

With the `#foo` element having your `text-overflow` declaration, and the `bar` class having a `white-space: nowrap` declaration. The you should be able to do something like this using jQuery:

```
var foo = $("#foo");
var max_width = foo.width();
foo.children().each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.width() > max_width) {
    $this.attr("title", $this.text());
  }
});
```

See: http://jsbin.com/alepa3